# How to convert the data from a wildcard into a string

Tags: powershell, active-directory, data-cleaning

I am trying to trim down strings located inside of a .csv so that they only contain the data I need. An example string might be "\path\folder\folder\folder\folder Owner = John Doe".

I just want the John doe part.

Currently I'm importing a list of about 6000 of these strings some have the line some don't.

What I'm trying is:

```
$owners = Import-Csv .\Owners.csv

ForEach($owner in $owners){
    if ($owner.Description -like "= *") {$owner.Description = "*"}
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to save the wildcard as a variable?

Comment: `$owner.Description = $owner.Description.Split('=')[-1].Trim()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to use a Regular Expression rather than Wildcard globbing.

```
$owners = Import-Csv .\Owners.csv

$output = foreach ($owner in $owners) {
    # The Description Property has an equal sign followed by a space
    if ($owner.Description -like '*= *') {
        # Use a regex then capture the the text after the equals and space, replace the property with that capture group.
        $owner.Description = $owner.Description -replace '.*=\s(.*)$', '$1'
        $owner
    }
}

$output | Export-Csv .\Owners.update.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: that does make more sense, but could you explain '.*=\s(.*)$', '$1' I'm trying to wrap my head around it, but i have no idea what I'm looking at.

Comment: @BPengu `.*` is zero or more of any character, `=\s` is an equal sign followed by a space character, `(.*)` is a capture group of zero of more of any character. and `$` is end of line then `$1` is the first capture group. So all together, the line can start with anything but has a `=` then space character in it, capture what comes after that until the end of the line, then replace everything with that capture group.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regex and match:

## CSV:

```
Description
\path\folder\folder\folder\folder Owner = John Doe
\path\folder\folder\folder\folder Owner = Captain Black
```

## Code:

```
$owners = Import-Csv .\Owners.csv

ForEach($owner in $owners){
    $match = $owner.Description -match "= .*"
    if ($match){
        $owner.Description = $matches[0] -replace "= ", ""
    }
    echo $owner
}
```

## Output:

```
Description  
-----------  
John Doe     
Captain Black
```